# Blazor dynamically createElement and appendChild

Tags: dynamic, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-jsinterop

i want to dynamically create DIV Containers via JSInterop in Blazor Webassembly. My approach was to create a CreateElement method in C# which calls createElement in javascript and returns a ElementReference as a Result. But when i run the Following code, i just get an empty object.

C# code:

```
public object CreateElement(ElementReference elementReference)
{
    return JsRuntime.Invoke<object>("createElement",
        elementReference,
        DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
}
```

Javascript code:

```
createElement(element, objectReference) {
            const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            return element.appendChild(newDiv);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason to do this in JS? Instead of C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need JS for that. Blazor was made so you don't have to manipulate the DOM. Create components. Manipulating the DOM this way defeats the purpose for which Blazor was made.  You may want to start with some basics at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: This answer is useless. It just linked a thousand-line-long document, without telling which specific part is addressing this problem. I could just link the index page of the .NET documentation website to every .NET question and say "learn the basics".

Comment: @DamnVegetables I don't think this is useless. Basically, what it states is that the OP's approach is not the right one for Blazor, and that he must first learn what it is all about: the creation of components. It links to the 2020 documents, which they refer to netcore 3.1., the state of the framework in 2020

Comment: @DamnVegetables whilst there are a lot of generic answers in SO, I think this one is fair enough.   The OP didn't mention any special case which requires dynamically creating elements with JS interop, therefore the completely logical response is to direct the OP toward creating components within Blazor itself.  If you look at the comments Henk has even said the same - and this is an SO serious big hitter.  I've upvoted this answer as a result.

Answer (score 0):

As @Porkopek mentioned, there's not really a good reason to do this as it more or less defeats the purpose of using Blazor to dynamically render markup.

If you absolutely have to use `createElement`, you should bind your JS interop code to the `window` object to invoke:

```
window.createDivElement = createElement(element, objectReference) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  return element.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Side note, `DotNetObjectReference.Create(this)` is for calling back into C# component methods via the `[JSInvokable]` attribute and probably not needed here.